# Now installing Ubuntu the same warning as when trying to install gparted - Warning - Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Remote 1/0 error

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

Attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 from DVD. Checked disk, no error. Same warning-error window appeared when attempting to install gparted! Ran: dmesg ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkCentre-M58p:~$ dmesg There appeared 30 000 script and of course I could not include that much. The terminal then suggested I run fsck then came this warning, I did not continue.

```
VARNING!!!  Filsystemet är monterat.  Om du fortsätter ***KOMMER***
du att orsaka ***ALLVARLIG*** skada på filsystemet.
```

Google Translated (from Swedish):

```
WARNING!!! The file system is mounted. If you continue *** COMES ***
you to cause *** SERIOUS *** damage to the file system.
```

Answer (score 0):

The system is suggesting that you run `fsck` on the problem drive.  You can't (safely) run `fsck` on a mounted disk.

You have to boot from a Live USB disk, then run the command while the drive isn't mounted.

---

Your output from the comments and chat is showing that you have one drive in your computer `/dev/sda`

You inadvertently tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a USB drive which is `/dev/sdb` (the output of the error message) which isn't formatted correctly for Linux.

Boot to the Live Disk and use the Install option type, Install Alongside Ubuntu.  The option will give you a slider to decide how much space your new install will get.  Since you mentioned you'll be deleting the Ubuntu 17.10, move the slider to provide as much space to version 16.04 as you can.

After you have created your new 16.04 install you can work from there and backup your date from your 17.10 install.  Then boot to the Live Media again and delete the 17.04 partition and add it to your new working 16.04 installation.

Alternatively, outside the **Alongside** option you can choose, something else, and specify the partition for the install.

In the chat you said you don't have any data you want saved from the previous install (which is on `/dev/sda1`).  In such case you can specify that partition for the destination.

Having a swap partition isn't imperative, but I would recommend a swap partition as part of your configuration.  So in order to include a swap partition, you'd best boot into the Live Disk, run `gparted`, then create a `swap` partition that is one and a half size of the amount of ram you have in your computer.  Then specify the other partition as your root drive `/` when you get to the option of where to install Ubuntu.

You can find the details of the install option (with pictures included) by navigating the official Ubuntu Download site.  Look at:
[The Official Installation Guide with Pictures](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76167/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-now-installing-ubuntu-the-same-warning-as-wh).

Comment: @L. D. James   Another failed attempt to install Ubuntu. While deciding on partition % I wanted for each version a window appeared (again) and `stated` that if the errors were not fixed I would have to go back to the partitioning. I ignored this continued. Then another window opened partitioning failed and I had to go- back. Eventually it crashed. I sent a report. Can the DVD be corrupted? Can one check? My other download there was a possibility to check, but not this one.

Comment: @GraemeBooth Comments are not for extended discussions.  Please use [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76167/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-now-installing-ubuntu-the-same-warning-as-wh).